# How to do Web Scraping with BeautifulSoup without affecting my PyQt5 application?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pyqt5, multiprocessing

I am making an application that **involves taking websites and getting the links they have** (and also images), but these operations take some time and **cause the application to freeze**. I've tried using **QThread** and **QRunnable** to try and **separate the execution of the application from the execution of the functions** I use.
I programmed this small example of how it works in my app:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QLineEdit,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600,64)
        
## Set a QLineEdit

        self.Line=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.Line.setPlaceholderText('You should be able to type here while the links are searched')
        self.Line.setFixedSize(600,32)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Line)

## Set a QPushButton

        self.Button=QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Button.setText('Seach links')
        self.Button.move(0,32)
        self.Button.setFixedSize(600,32)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Button)

## Connect button with function

        self.Button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.search_start())

## Function calls QProcess class

    def search_start(self):
        self.sclass=search_class()
        self.sclass.func_seach()

## Class search for links

class search_class(QThread):
    def func_seach(self):
        url='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ'
        links_list=[]
        for link in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a'):
            links_list.append(link.get('href'))
        print(links_list)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Aplication=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    MainWindow=mainwindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    Aplication.exec_()
```

**How can I prevent the app from freezing while executing that function?**
I think you may have already noticed that I'm pretty new to this. I need to know what's wrong, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it.
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You need to override the `run` method of `QThread`, so place everything under `func_seach` inside `run` method and call `start` method eg: `self.sclass.start()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to **put the entire class below in a function** inside the first class and **trigger my function through another function that started the other one in a thread**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow,QLineEdit,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600,64)
        self.Line=QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.Line.setPlaceholderText('You should be able to type here while the links are searched')
        self.Line.setFixedSize(600,32)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Line)

## Set a QPushButton

        self.Button=QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.Button.setText('Seach links')
        self.Button.move(0,32)
        self.Button.setFixedSize(600,32)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.Button)

## Connect button with function

        self.Button.clicked.connect(lambda:self.search_start())

## Function calls func_seach function as a thread

    def search_start(self):
        thread=Thread(target=self.func_seach)
        thread.start()


    def func_seach(self):
        url='https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ'
        links_list=[]
        for link in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser').find_all('a'):
            links_list.append(link.get('href'))
        print(links_list)

if __name__=='__main__':
    Aplication=QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    MainWindow=mainwindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    Aplication.exec_()
```